# how to ask for permission to use the webcam in javafx?

Tags: webview, javafx-2, javafx

I´ve got a webapplication that uses the webcam. When I run it on a browser it works and ofcourse it ask me my permission to use the webcam. So is there a way in javafx to ask for the camera?
Here is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {
   @Override
   public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
       StackPane root = new StackPane();

       WebView view = new WebView();
       WebEngine engine = view.getEngine();
       engine.load("http://localhost/Step2.html");
       root.getChildren().add(view);

       System.out.println(engine.isJavaScriptEnabled());

       Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
       stage.setScene(scene);
       stage.show();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       Application.launch(args);
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

[JavaFX 2.2 has no webcam support](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-3458).

You will be unable to get your JavaFX application to use a webcam from within a [WebView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) until both the underlying JavaFX platform and WebView support such a configuration.

As you mention that you can enable webcam support in your system browser, you can instead open your webcam enabled html page in a web browser using [HostServices.showDocument](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/HostServices.html#showDocument%28java.lang.String%29).